# En c++ me aparece Error (activo) E2020: el tipo nullptr administrado no se puede usar aquí y no se a que se pueda deber

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Cuando escribo codigo en c++ (console app. CLR) me sale error E2020: el tipo nullptr administrado no se puede usar aquí.Pero no se a que se deba ya que me aparece en varios codigos que escribo y no me deja correr ninguno debido a esto, mostrare un ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando hago doble clic en el error me aparece esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Agradecería mucho que alguien me ayude ya que he buscado en internet y no he encontrado la respuesta.

Comment: Por lo visto estás usando funcionalidad nueva. Ve a las propiedades del proyecto y prueba cambiando la versión a C++20 o más reciente.

Answer (score 0):

Me he dado cuenta de que ese error, al menos en mi caso salia al no colocar informacion sobre que net framework estaba dirijido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]