# Errores de compilación usando código nativo C++ en proyecto C++/CLI

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de usar código nativo C++ en una proyecto de consola C++ (CLR), y estoy consiguiendo errores, NO en el código, sino en el archivo "exception".  Estoy usando Visual Studio 2022 Community y su respectiva plantilla.  He realizado la prueba 2 computadoras diferentes (Windows 10 y 11), y consigo los mismos errores ¿Por favor, alguien podría darme una idea de la solución?  Adjunto imagen de un simple código "hello world".
[image: Errores E2020]

Comment: Tal vez esto te pueda ayudar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/592602/en-c-me-aparece-error-activo-e2020-el-tipo-nullptr-administrado-no-se-puede

Comment: Gracias por responder.  Continúan los errores al cambiar la versión a C++20.